# msbuild with p:RunOctoPack missing files

Tags: nuget-package, octopus-deploy, msbuild-4.0

DLLs are missing when I package using MSBuild.
msbuild ./MyProject.vbproj /p:RunOctoPack=true  /p:OctoPackEnforceAddingFiles=true

There are no missing files if I use octo pack directly
octo pack --id="testing" --format="zip" --version="3.3.3" --basepath="MyProject\bin\debug"

Both of these commands work on the same folder, and I have verified the files exist in that folder.

The missing files are from the ActivePDF nuget package.  The files are created in the bin/debug folder during the build process.

From MS Build:
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET Framework
OctoPack: OctoPack version: 3.6.4.0
For Octo pack directly.
".octopack/octo" version 4.42.2

Msbuild uses an octo nuget package and there is no version 4.x.

My nuspec is trivial:


MyProject
MyProject Title
0.1.0
Dev Team
Me
http://temp.abc
http://temp.abc
false
MyProject